# Wix Build Error

Tags: c#, wix

When running wix I get the following Error:

with error MSB4019: The imported project “C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure about other problems that might cause this but I was unaware that Wix is not installed alongside ms build.

I was trying to build a project that was sat on our build server and ran into this problem.

You need to download and install it from http://wix.sourceforge.net/ first.

Another commonly used package is MSBuild Community tasks which is available from

https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks

The last stable release is downloadable from the bit called nightly builds!

This will give a similar error message.

Answer (score 1):

To check your Visual Studio version

1. VS 2017 [download](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WixToolset.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension)
   [image]
2. VS 2019 [download](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WixToolset.WixToolsetVisualStudio2019Extension)

[image]

3. VS 2022 [download](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WixToolset.WixToolsetVisualStudio2022Extension)
   [image]